# How to "keep-alive" with cookielib and httplib in python?

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2, httplib

In python, I'm using httplib because it "keep-alive" the http connection (as oppose to urllib(2)). Now, I want to use cookielib with httplib but they seem to hate each other!! (no way to interface them together).

Does anyone know of a solution to that problem?

Comment: is using httplib a requirement?  cookielib works great with urllib2 and you can add your own keep-alive headers.

Comment: To keep everything consistent, you may want to change all the references to capitalize() by lower() and has_header and get_headers key converted to lower as well

Answer (score 2):

[HTTP handler for urllib2 that supports keep-alive](http://urlgrabber.baseurl.org/help/urlgrabber.keepalive.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using the [`Requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library instead at the earliest chance you have to refactor your code. In the mean time;

HACK ALERT! :)

I'd go other suggested way, but I've done a hack (done for different reasons though), which does create an interface between [httplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) and [cookielib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html).

What I did was creating a fake `HTTPRequest` with minimal required set of methods, so that [`CookieJar`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.CookieJar) would recognize it and process cookies as needed. I've used that fake request object, setting all the data needed for cookielib.

Here is the code of the class:

```
class HTTPRequest( object ):
"""
Data container for HTTP request (used for cookie processing).
"""

    def __init__( self, host, url, headers={}, secure=False ):
        self._host = host
        self._url = url
        self._secure = secure
        self._headers = {}
        for key, value in headers.items():
            self.add_header(key, value)

    def has_header( self, name ):
        return name in self._headers

    def add_header( self, key, val ):
        self._headers[key.capitalize()] = val

    def add_unredirected_header(self, key, val):
        self._headers[key.capitalize()] = val

    def is_unverifiable( self ):
        return True

    def get_type( self ):
        return 'https' if self._secure else 'http'

    def get_full_url( self ):
        port_str = ""
        port = str(self._host[1])
        if self._secure:
            if port != 443:
                port_str = ":"+port
        else:
            if port != 80:
                port_str = ":"+port
        return self.get_type() + '://' + self._host[0] + port_str + self._url

    def get_header( self, header_name, default=None ):
        return self._headers.get( header_name, default )

    def get_host( self ):
        return self._host[0]

    get_origin_req_host = get_host

    def get_headers( self ):
        return self._headers
```

Please note, the class has support for HTTPS protocol only (all I needed at the moment).

The code, which used this class was (please note another hack to make response compatible with cookielib):

```
cookies = CookieJar()

headers = {
    # headers that you wish to set
}

# construct fake request
fake_request = HTTPRequest( host, request_url, headers )

# add cookies to fake request
cookies.add_cookie_header(fake_request)

# issue an httplib.HTTPConnection based request using cookies and headers from the fake request
http_connection.request(type, request_url, body, fake_request.get_headers())

response = http_connection.getresponse()

if response.status == httplib.OK:
    # HACK: pretend we're urllib2 response
    response.info = lambda : response.msg

    # read and store cookies from response
    cookies.extract_cookies(response, fake_request)

    # process response...
```

Comment: This hack just saved me a couple hours of reimplementing more or less the same thing myself.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome, Zack! That's the main reason for sharing. :)