# Scrapy domain_name for spider

Tags: python, scrapy

From the Scrapy tutorial:

> domain_name: identifies the Spider. It must be unique, that is, you can’t set the same domain name for different Spiders.

Does this mean that `domain_name` must be a valid domain name, like

> domain_name = 'example.com'

Or can I name

```
domain_name = 'ex1'
```

The problem is I had a spider that worked with domain name

```
domain_name = 'whitecase.com'
```

Now I created a new spider as an instance of CrawlSpider and named it

```
domain_name = 'wc2'
```

but I am getting the error `"could not find spider for domain "wc2""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

> domain_name = 'wc2'

works.

Answer (score 0):

As you have found out yourself, `domain_name` shouldn't be real. It's used when calling the spider to crawl.