# Library like fakeweb for Python

Tags: python, testing, fakeweb

I really like the way fakeweb in Ruby can be used to fake http requests when testing. Is there a similar library or an alternative for Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See also [How can one mock/stub python module like urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295438/how-can-one-mock-stub-python-module-like-urllib/295503) . The answer that recommends [Mox](http://code.google.com/p/pymox/) seems the most like fakeweb, but Mox lets you create fake versions of any module, not just urllib.

For incoming requests, if your web framework uses WebOb ([repoze.bfg](http://bfg.repoze.org/), [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/) others), you can use [`webob.Request.blank`](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/reference.html#id1).

```
from webob import Request
r = Request.blank('/')
a_view_function(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

[HTTPretty](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty) works in the exact same way that FakeWeb does. HTTPretty works in the socket layer, so it should work intercepting any python http client libraries. It's battle tested against urllib2, httplib2 and requests

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you produce a fake inteface to HTTP request like in [questions 1016765 how-to-use-cookielib-with-httplib-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016765/how-to-use-cookielib-with-httplib-in-python).

Comment: I don't know of a similar lib.